# Slider with left/right arrows

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic3, swiper.js

Could you tell me how can I create right/left arrows for the Ionic slider component?

**Demo:** [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-avgj1t)

*Note:* please see the `home.html` page

[image]

*.html*

```
<ion-slides  [pager]="true" [slidesPerView]="2">
        <ion-slide>
            <h1>Slide 1</h1>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
            <h1>Slide 2</h1>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
            <h1>Slide 3</h1>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? The question includes a demo project where the issue can be reproduced and also includes an image of the desired output... It has been flagged as "too broad" but it doesn't seem to be that kind of questions either.

Comment: Yes, Really frustrating. But I'm very happy since I got the solution and also about your comment. Thanks @sebaferreras  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create two buttons.

- A back button:

`<button (click)="this.Slides.slidePrev()" class="backBtn"> 
   <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon> 
 </button>`

- A next Button:

`<button (click)="this.Slides.slideNext()" class="nextBtn"> 
   <ion-icon name="arrow-forward">
 </ion-icon> </button>`

***Note:*** This is just a `pseudo code` `(click)="this.Slides.slidePrev()"`

You'll then need to position them with your css and you should be good to go :)

CSS:

```
.backBtn{
   position: absolute;
   left: 20vw;
   top: 40vh;
   width: 15vw;
   height: 15vw;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: none;
   background: red;
}

.nextBtn{
   position: absolute;
   right: 20vw;
   top: 40vh;
   width: 15vw;
   height: 15vw;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: none;
   background: green;
}
```

Comment: Yes, But CSS part is the tricky part :(  Any help there with `Stackblitz` above?

Comment: I just added some css for you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great support :)